# Connection refused with psql django and docker (cookiecutter-django)

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, cookiecutter-django

My django app is failing to connect to the psql container  with the standard connection refused error.  I used django-cookiecutter which supplies the psql username and password automatically via environment variables and then this I gather is passed back into django with via a .env file that hosts a DATABASE_URL string.

Error

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

When I set a breakpoint in django settings I can see that the DATABASE_URL seems to be converted appropriately into the standard db dict:

```
{'NAME': 'hustlestat', 'USER': 'HjhPLEwuVjUIIKEHebPqNG<redacted>', 'PASSWORD': 'I43443fR42wRkUaaQ8mkd<redacted>', 'HOST': 'postgres', 'PORT': 5432, 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql'}
```

When I exec into the psql container with `psql hustlestat -U HjhPLEwuVjUIIKEHebPqN<redcated>` I can connect to the db using that username.  I'm not 100% on the password as it isn't asking me for one when I try to connect.

Here is the docker compose which is generated automatically by cookie cutter:

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  local_postgres_data: {}
  local_postgres_data_backups: {}

services:
  django: &django
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/django/Dockerfile
    image: hustlestat_local_django
    container_name: django
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - mailhog
    volumes:
      - .:/app:z
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.django
      - ./.envs/.local/.postgres
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: /start

  postgres:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/postgres/Dockerfile
    image: hustlestat_production_postgres
    container_name: postgres
    volumes:
      - local_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:Z
      - local_postgres_data_backups:/backups:z
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.postgres

  docs:
    image: hustlestat_local_docs
    container_name: docs
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/docs/Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.django
    volumes:
      - ./docs:/docs:z
      - ./config:/app/config:z
      - ./hustlestat:/app/hustlestat:z
    ports:
      - "7000:7000"
    command: /start-docs

  mailhog:
    image: mailhog/mailhog:v1.0.0
    container_name: mailhog
    ports:
      - "8025:8025"

  redis:
    image: redis:5.0
    container_name: redis

  celeryworker:
    <<: *django
    image: hustlestat_local_celeryworker
    container_name: celeryworker
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - postgres
      - mailhog
    ports: []
    command: /start-celeryworker

  celerybeat:
    <<: *django
    image: hustlestat_local_celerybeat
    container_name: celerybeat
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - postgres
      - mailhog
    ports: []
    command: /start-celerybeat

  flower:
    <<: *django
    image: hustlestat_local_flower
    container_name: flower
    ports:
      - "5555:5555"
    command: /start-flower

  node:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/node/Dockerfile
    image: hustlestat_local_node
    container_name: node
    depends_on:
      - django
    volumes:
      - .:/app:z
      # http://jdlm.info/articles/2016/03/06/lessons-building-node-app-docker.html
      - /app/node_modules
    command: npm run dev
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      # Expose browsersync UI: https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/#option-ui
      - "3001:3001"
```

The only oddity I have noticed is that despite django being named in the docker compose, when I view the running containers it has a random name such as:

```
hustlestat_django_run_37888ff2c9ca
```

Not sure if that is relevant.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4):

Okay have figured this out.  I set a DATABASE_URL environment variable because I was originally getting an error saying it was unset.  After googling I came across a cookie cutter doc that said to set it but didn't read it well enough to realise that the instruction was intended for non-docker setups.  Mine is docker.

The reason I was getting that error is because I was exec'ing into the container and running management commands like this:
`docker exec -it django bash` then `python manage.py migrate`

The way this project is setup and environment variables are setup, you can't do that, you have to use this method from outside the exec:

`docker-compose -f local.yml run --rm django python manage.py migrate`

I thought the two methods were interchangeable but they are not.  Everything works now.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! love yooou - The issue also the same when doing 'python manage.py shell' command.. suddenly no connection. Now I know. :D